# jQuery: How to select the next element with name-xyz?

Tags: jquery, dom, toggle

I'm trying to build a really simple generic toggle functionality where the toggling "switch" has a class of `.toggle` and then I want it to `toggle()` the next element that has the class `.toggle-content`.

Example HTML:

```
<p>
  <a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle the thing</a>
</p>
<p class="toggle-content hidden">I'm totally hidden right now</p>
```

So right now I'd toggle that with:

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().next('.toggle-content').toggle();
});
```

The problem is if the `.toggle` class is any deeper in the DOM, I have to keep tacking on more `parent()`'s depending on how deep it is/isn't.

So how can I just select the next instance of `.toggle-content` without having use a bunch of `parent()`'s and `next()`'s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`closest()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method instead of the [`parent()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method.

```
$(this).closest('p').next('.toggle-content').toggle();
```

This will fetch the first `<p>` ancestor that it finds.

*(Technically, it begins on the `this` element itself, but since you can't have nested `<p>` elements, that shouldn't be an issue.)*

---

**EDIT:** If you can't target a specific tag, and you can't assign a class to use as a target, do this:

```
$(this).parentsUntil('> .toggle-content:last').next('.toggle-content').toggle();
```

It uses the [`parentsUntil()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) method to get all ancestors until it finds one that has a child `.toggle-content` element. It does this using the [`child-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

Because it stops just before that one, you'll be at the correct level.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/yCG72/

---

Otherwise, you could just do a filter using the [`filter()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```
$(this).parents().filter(function(){
    return $(this).next('.toggle-content').length;
}).first().next('.toggle-content').toggle();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/yCG72/1/

Comment: The `<p>` tag could be really any tag (fieldset, legend, div, section, etc), so ideally I wouldn't set that.

Comment: @Shpigford: You'll need some sort of target. If it could be any tag, you should put a class on it. Otherwise it will become needlessly complicated. `$(this).closest('.toggler').next(...`

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `.closest()` and `.nextAll()`:

```
$(this).closest('p').nextAll('.toggle-content:first').toggle();
```

The `.nextAll()` handles cases where the first `.toggle-content` may not be the **immediate** next element.

---

For actually recursively searching for the "next" element with a certain class, irrespective of what level it is at, it gets a little more complex, but can be done if we write our own short jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.nextR = function (selector) {
    var el;
    if (this.children().length) {
        el = this.children().eq(0);
    } else if (this.next().length) {
        el = this.next();
    } else {
        el = this.parent().next();
    }

    if (selector && !el.is(selector) && el.length) {
        el = el.nextR(selector);
    }
    return el;
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
$(this).nextR('.toggle-content').toggle();
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4uVM5/